# How to upgrade Laravel 5.2 to most recent version?

Tags: laravel, symfony, composer-php

I am a new developer on the website I work on. I have downloaded the source code which is a Laravel project- currently version 5.2. I am trying to implement functionality that can only be done in version 5.4 and later. I figured that I may as well update to Laravel 5.7 whilst I'm at it. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Bit by bit. Each version of Laravel includes instructions to upgrade from the previous, so you'll do 5.2 --> 5.3, then 5.3 --> 5.4, etc. Some are more complicated than others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [upgrade guides](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) but they might take a lot of time, you can also use [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) if you're willing to pay.